# Why is gdb getting SEGV when I manually call a function on a std::vector?

Tags: c++, gdb, stdvector, segmentation-fault

After moving to Centos 5 (from 4) I'm seeing gdb crashing when I try to call a member function on an std::vector:

```
(gdb) p actionQueue->size()

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x081d881e in indexedActionQueue::size (this=0xbfbd0050) at actionList.h:52
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB has restored the context to what it was before the call.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal off".
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(indexedActionQueue::size() const) will be abandoned.
(gdb) p actionQueue->_actionQueue
$1 = std::vector of length 7, capacity 7 = {
   [...]
    }
(gdb) p actionQueue->_actionQueue.empty()

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08158ea3 in std::vector<CAction, std::allocator<CAction> >::empty (this=0xa514788) at /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_vector.h:735
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB has restored the context to what it was before the call.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal off".
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(std::vector<CAction, std::allocator<CAction> >::empty() const) will be abandoned.
(gdb) p actionQueue->_actionQueue.begin()

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08188ec6 in std::vector<CAction, std::allocator<CAction> >::begin (this=0xa514788) at /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_vector.h:539
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB has restored the context to what it was before the call.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal off".
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(std::vector<CAction, std::allocator<CAction> >::begin()) will be abandoned.
```

I tried updating gdb to v7.9 but I got the same results.  I'm using `scl enable devtoolset-2` to build with gcc v4.8.2. If I print the `std::vector` in gdb it looks proper.

If I place the methods that get SEGV directly into the C++ application they run without SEGV, but manually running them in gdb gets a SEGV.

How can I get gdb to allow these calls to work?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what caused this and how to fix it? I'm getting the same issue on Cygwin except I have an instance of a vector and not a pointer to one.

Comment: Not that I recall.  I think I just worked around it.  Maybe try a later version of GDB?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing is that I remember being able to do this on older versions of gdb. It's just on the current version where this started happening. I'll keep looking into it and see if I can find something.